# Identify oldest Kafka offset that has data for consumption

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I ran into this data issue today and to solve it I have to recalculate everything from the last 3 months. But, in Kafka when I run this command :

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 10.8.95.21:9092 --topic backoffice --from-beginning
```

it encounters an error : `The requested offset is not within the range of offsets maintained by the server`

The `--from-beginning` is trying to get data from Offsets whose data has been purged by kafka.
Can I list offsets alongwith the time it was created? So, that I can estimate from where I can start consuming data. Otherwise, if I can identify the oldest Kafka Offset that has data, I can start reading from that offset.

Comment: By using the `GetOffsetShell` tool, you can list earliest offsets for a particular topic 

But otherwise, that command should return you the earliest messages without throwing that error... Try giving a few more broker addresses

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried out  **kt** ([fgeller/kt](https://github.com/fgeller/kt)). This is an amazing tool as an alternative to Kafka console tools. This is written in go, so amazingly fast also. And one other advantage is you can get offset of each message by default there.

So you can simply write something like :
  `kt consume -brokers <broker-name> -topic <topic-name> oldest`

and the output will be something like this : 
`{
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": <oldest-offset>,
    "key": "<your-key>",
    "value": "<value of the message>" 
}`

Edit: If you want some UI for this, [Kafdrop](https://github.com/HomeAdvisor/Kafdrop) is just what you are looking for. Setting it up is pretty easy and you can get all offset related information quite easily. You can even watch a message corresponding to an offset which is pretty amazing.

Comment: somehow kt doesn't work for me. And slow too.

Answer (score 0):

The following cmd worked for me:

`./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list <broker-name> --topic <topic-name> --time -2`